# Setting UITabBarIcon tint when unselected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I am trying to set the icons of a UITabBarItem, but it is not working. By the way, I'm using Xcode 5 Beta for this project.

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    {
        [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];
        [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

[image]

I am trying to get the icons to be white when both selected and unselected, but they are remaining gray in the unselected state.

---

## Edit

I tried doing this, but now im getting the error "Expression Result Unused"

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
        tabBarItem1.title = @"Home";
        UIImage *graph = [UIImage imageNamed:@"graph.png"];
        [tabBarItem1 initWithTitle:(NSString *)@"HELLO" image:(UIImage *)graph selectedImage:(UIImage *)graph];
```

Answer (score 0):

`tintColor` sets the tint color of the background, you can't see this if you use a custom background image. If you don't want to have the system default gradient you have to use [`setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/setFinishedSelectedImage%3awithFinishedUnselectedImage%3a) and set your white image for both of them.

Like this:

```
UIImage *selectedImage = ...
UIImage *unselectedImage = selectedImage;
[tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage];
```

If you are setting those images in a Storyboard you can iterate over the existing UITabBarItems and change their images.

Put something like this into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NSAssert([tabBarController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]], @"self.window.rootViewController must be a tabBarController");
for (UIViewController *viewController in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = viewController.tabBarItem;
    UIImage *tabImage = tabBarItem.image;
    [tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:tabImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:tabImage];
}
```

Comment: Im setting the images through storyboards. So I don't have a name for each tabBarItem.

Comment: you can't set the finished images from a storyboard, so you have to add some code to your app delegate. See edit.

Comment: is their a way to use this? `initWithTitle:(NSString *)@"title" image:(UIImage *)[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample image"] selectedImage:(UIImage *) [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample image"]];`

Comment: Your method is deprecated in ios 7